# Inequality $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{c+a^3+b^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc \geq 10+6\sqrt{3}$. Prove that: $$ \displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{c+a^3+b^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$

I've tried to bound the LHS of Michael Rozenberg's last inequality,

$\frac{3\left(7.5^{7.5}\cdot27\cdot6^6\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}}{16.5(10+6\sqrt3)^{\frac{6}{16.5}}} = \frac{3}{16.5}\cdot\left(\frac{7.5^{7.5}\cdot27\cdot6^6}{(10+6\sqrt3)^6}\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}} < \frac{3}{16.5}\cdot\left(\frac{7.5^{7.5}\cdot27\cdot6^6}{20^6}\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}$

$7.5^{7.5}=7.5^6\cdot7.5^{1.5}<7.5^6\cdot7.5^2 <7.5^6\cdot2^6$

$<\frac{3}{16.5}\cdot\left(\frac{15^6\cdot(\sqrt{3})^6\cdot6^6}{20^6}\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}=\frac{3}{16.5}\cdot\left(\frac{90\sqrt{3})^6}{20^6}\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}$

$=\frac{3}{16.5}\cdot\left(\frac{90\sqrt{3}}{20}\right)^{\frac{6}{16.5}}=\frac{3}{16.5}\cdot(4.5\sqrt{3})^{\frac{6}{16.5}}$

$<\frac{3}{16.5}\cdot(4.5\sqrt{3})^{\frac{1}{2}}<\frac{3}{16.5}\cdot(8)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\frac{3}{16.5}\cdot3=0.54$

Comment: Firstly think about the equality occurring.

Comment: What's $cyc$? $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=(1+\sqrt3)kx^2$, $b=(1+\sqrt3)ky^2$ and $c=(1+\sqrt3)kz^2$, where $k>0$ and $xyz=1$.

Hence, $10+6\sqrt3\leq abc=(10+6\sqrt3)k^3xyz$, which gives $k\geq1$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^3+b^2+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{k^2(1+\sqrt3)^2x^3+(1+\sqrt3)ky^2+z}\leq$$
$$\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{(1+\sqrt3)k(2\sqrt{x^3z}+y^2)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{3x^3+2y^2+z}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{3x^3+2y^2+z}\leq\frac{1}{2},$$
which is true, but it's very ugly.

In another hand, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^3+b^2+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{7.5\cdot\frac{a^3}{7.5}+3\cdot\frac{b^2}{3}+6\cdot\frac{c}{6}}\leq$$
$$\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{16.5\left(\frac{a^3}{7.5}\right)^{\frac{7.5}{16.5}}\cdot\left(\frac{b^6}{27}\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}\cdot\left(\frac{c^6}{6^6}\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}}=$$
$$=\frac{\left(7.5^{7.5}\cdot27\cdot6^6\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}}{16.5}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^{\frac{22.5}{16.5}}b^{\frac{6}{16.5}}c^{\frac{6}{16.5}}}=\frac{\left(7.5^{7.5}\cdot27\cdot6^6\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}}{16.5}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^{\frac{6}{16.5}}b^{\frac{6}{16.5}}c^{\frac{6}{16.5}}}=$$
$$=\frac{3\left(7.5^{7.5}\cdot27\cdot6^6\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}}{16.5(abc)^{\frac{6}{16.5}}}\leq\frac{3\left(7.5^{7.5}\cdot27\cdot6^6\right)^{\frac{1}{16.5}}}{16.5(10+6\sqrt3)^{\frac{6}{16.5}}}=0.3555...\leq\frac{1}{2}.$$
Done!

Comment: Thank you for simplifying the problem. I've tried to prove $\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{3x^3+2y^2+z}\leq\frac{1}{2}$ using Cauchy, Holder but my work looked ugly. I substituted $x=\frac{p}{q}, y=\frac{q}{r}, z=\frac{r}{p}$ and got this, $\sum_{cyc} \frac{p^2q^2r^2}{3p^4r^2+2pq^5+q^3r^3}$.Please suggest.

Comment: @carat I fixed. See now, please.

Comment: @carat We can prove the last inequality by hand! Try it. It's not so hard.

Comment: Please see my work above. At what point should I improve to make the LHS less than 0.5.